# OSX documentation for mknod

Tags: macos, audio, command-line-interface, mknod

I thought the documentation over at Apple was a little sparse on major/minor numbers for mknod.  I was trying to create a raw character device for the microphone so that I could pipe data into it.  On a proper linux system the kernel's ./Documentation/Devices.txt file contains the referenced major/minor numbers.  Has Apple created any corollary documentation for creating raw kernel character devices for hardware access?

ex.: `mknod dsp c 14 3`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm, why would you want to pipe data to the microfone node?

Answer (score 1):

OS X is not Linux-based. On OS X many hardware devices are not accessed through traditional Unix device nodes which is why there is no documentation for making a microphone raw device. OS X provides rich support for audio devices through its `Core Audio` framework.  See the [Core Audio Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) manual for more information on how to get started.